# If a link is already open in another window or tab I don't want duplicates to open. It's working in other browsers but Safari keeps opening new tabs

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tabs, safari, target

Here are two links that open in a new window or tab called "myNewWindow" (I have put the Google link here for comparison, and to illustrate the problem I am having - it is only Shutterstock that I am planning to link to from my site):

```html
<p><a href="http://shutterstock.com/video" target="myNewWindow">Shutterstock Footage</a></p>
<p><a href="http://google.com" target="myNewWindow">Google</a></p>
```

When I test this in Chrome, Firefox and Opera it behaves as I expect i.e. if "myNewWindow" is already open, then both links open in that tab. In Safari (7.1.5) there appears to be something about the Shutterstock link which prevents Safari from re-using that tab and forces it to open again in another new tab, which creates a duplicate tab for every time that link is clicked. If the Google link is open, then Safari can open the Shutterstock link over it in the same tab, but not vice versa.

Please can anyone suggest to me what might be going on here?

Comment: I tried it in Chrome it also opens a new window instead of reusing the Shuttershock window.

Comment: Opera, too. Only Firefox reuses the window.

Comment: It didn't matter whether I opened Google or ShutterStock first. Either way, the second link opened a new tab.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for replying! Interesting that you are seeing those different results, and it makes me feel that for safety and consistency I should just set all targets to "_self" (default), and forget about trying to open new tabs. I double-checked Chrome 42, Firefox 37, Opera 28 on OS X 10.9.5 and Chrome 41, Firefox 36, Opera 27 on Windows 8.1, and IE 8,9,10,11 on Windows 7, and I am seeing them all re-use the same tab, which is different to your test. I noticed that after that tab has been opened once, IE and Firefox don't switch focus to it when either of the links is clicked again.

Comment: FYI, I just copied your HTML above to jsfiddle. Can you reproduce the problem there, or do you only see it on your website.

Comment: Using jsfiddle I can recreate your results except in one respect: the links don't work at all in Firefox.